# Rxjs Typings for Typescript

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'm using AngularJS with typescript and I don't have a module loader so I cannot use imports and I can't use the default Rxjs typings. All other typings I use are global and don't need to be imported (angular for example). Could you suggest how to use rxjs with typescript without the need to use modules, imports and exports?
There is @types/rx but is version 4 and is not compatible with rxjs version 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who might have the same problem, I figured a solution for myself.
I added a separate d.ts file so I can import the Rx definitions and then export them as a global namespace:

```
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';

export as namespace Rx;

declare class Observable<T> extends Rx.Observable<T> {

}

interface Observer<T> extends Rx.Observer<T> {

}
```

Then I can call `Rx.Observable` from anywhere without any imports.